# Trying to add a click event handler to the LI element and fetch the content in alert box

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I am trying to add a click event handler to the LI element and fetch its content in an alert box. Only the first of the element's content gets fetched into the alert box. Can you help me to get the text of each element on the click event?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("ul")[1].onclick = function(){
    alert(this.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">    
  <ul class="item-container">
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you query the `ul` element?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to add a click event to each `li` element instead of `ul`.

Here's an example:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("li")].forEach(li => li.onclick = function(){
    alert(this.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <ul class="item-container">
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 5</a></li>
  <li><a class="items" href="#">Item 6</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```